# Hypergeometric $\lim_{z\to 1}{}_3F_2(a,b,c;d,e;z)$ with $a+b+c-d-e=0$?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Is there anything special one can say about a hypergeometric function

$$\lim_{z\to 1}{}_3F_2\left({{a,b,c}\atop{d,e}};z\right)$$

in the case when $a+b+c-d-e=0$?

Comment: I used Mathematica ''FullSimplify[HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b, c}, {d, e}, 1], 
 Assumptions -> 
  Element[a | b | c | d | e, Integers] && a + b + c - d - e == 0]'', and there is no simplification.

Comment: What I notice is that trying to evaluate it at various $a,b,c,d,e$ (not integers) seems to give infinity. Maybe I should not put $z=1$ but rather consider the limit $z\to 1$. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a+b+c=d+e$ then ${_3F}_2(\mathbf a;\mathbf b;z)$ is said to be zero-balanced which results in a logarithmic singularity at $z=1$. Specifically, as $z\to 1$:
$$
{_3F}_2\left({a,b,c \atop d,e};z\right)\sim-\frac{\Gamma(d)\Gamma(e)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}\log(1-z).
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{z\to 1}{_3F}_2\left({a,b,c \atop d,e};z\right)=\infty.
$$

See [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.27.06.0016.01) for more details.